# Mouse middle button press and drag from left to right in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an application where I want to click and hold mouse middle button and then drag the mouse from left to right.

I have tried below code using robot API but no luck yet.

```
robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.*VK_ALT*);
robo.delay(500);
robo.mousePress();
robo.delay(500);
robo.mouseRelease();
robo.delay(500);
robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.*VK_ALT*);
```

Comment: Use Selenium Action class, examples [here](https://www.guru99.com/keyboard-mouse-events-files-webdriver.html)

Comment: I already tried that but not sure how to press middle mouse button

Comment: Ok i think you need to use mousePress() instead of key press. Try `robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK)` [Source](https://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html)

Comment: Yesterday I have tried robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);  which is working fine but now the problem is to move the mouse pointer to right.

Comment: Ok found solution ..        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);
  
   WebElement e1=getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Test']//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[12]//a[1]"));
    WebElement e1=getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Test']//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//a[1]"));
   withAction().moveToElement(e1).build().perform();
   withAction().moveToElement(e2).build().perform();

   robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);

Comment: Cool, best if you paste that as your answer to the question so it helps others that may find this question. Glad to hear you sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution :

```
Robot robot;
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK); 
WebElement e1=getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Test']//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[12]//a[1]"));
WebElement e1=getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Test']//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//a[1]")); action.moveToElement(e1).build().perform(); 
action.moveToElement(e2).build().perform(); 
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);
```